# How to pipe YAML into EJS in a Gulp stream?

Tags: stream, yaml, gulp, ejs

I'm using [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/). I want to pipe the resulting JSON data from [gulp-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-yaml), straight into [gulp-ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ejs). My logic says that I'm probably going to have to get synchronous at some point?

What I have tried thus far:

```
var yaml = require('gulp-yaml');
var ejs = require('gulp-ejs');

gulp.task('yaml', function(){

    return gulp.src('./path/to/template.ejs')
        .pipe( ejs( gulp.src('./path/to/data.yml').pipe( yaml() ) ) )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./path/to/dest'));

});
```

I realise that the above is an idiotic script as I'm essentially trying to pass a stream as an argument to `ejs`. And as predicted, it doesn't work. I've tried numerous other things but I'm guessing someone has done this before?

I reckon [gulp-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data) will have something to do with the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need the gulp-data plugin to achieve this; like you said you're just passing the option synchronously to the ejs plugin, and you're only needing the one yaml config file. So this is probably better:

```
var yaml = require('js-yaml');
var ejs = require('gulp-ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('ejs-with-yaml', function () {
    return gulp.src('path/to/template.ejs')
        .pipe(ejs(yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('path/to/data.yml', 'utf-8'))))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/dest'));
});
```

Comment: for an up-vote, how would I handle an error for a non-existent yml file here?

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to "handle" this error, as it's not exactly a task that can continue onwards if the YAML data was not found. `fs.readFileSync` will just throw `ENOENT` if the file doesn't exist, from there you know that your data doesn't exist and you can rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a bit of head-scratching I've been able to find a solution using [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) and [gulp-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data).

```
var yaml = require('js-yaml');
var ejs = require('gulp-ejs');
var data = require('gulp-data');

gulp.task('ejs-with-yaml', function(){

    return gulp.src('path/to/data.yml'))
        .pipe(data(function(file, cb){

            // throughput the stream in case of bad/absent file data
            if (file.isNull()) return cb( null, file );
            if (file.isStream()) return cb( new Error("Streaming not supported") );

            // try and convert yaml to json
            try {
                json = yaml.load(String(file.contents.toString('utf8')));
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

            gulp.src('path/to/template.ejs').pipe(ejs(json)).pipe(gulp.dest( 'path/to/dest' ));

        }));
});
```

Hopefully this might help others that are stuck on this. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to comment.

Comment: have updated correct answer to Ben's at it is simpler/cleaner.